# MYSQL AFTER Trigger UPDATE IF

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to UPDATE my row after it has been updated by the user.
Example if after the user selects 32, and Principal previously entered is > 1000. Then Update the 32 to 40.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateusers_id AFTER UPDATE ON Table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN       

IF(NEW.users_id = 32 AND Table.Principal > 50000) THEN
UPDATE loans SET users_id = 40;
END IF;

END
```

Comment: That's nice... what exactly is the problem?

Comment: MySql Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: also if i do this  BEGIN       

IF(SELECT users_id FROM loans WHERE Principal > 50001) = 32 THEN
UPDATE loans SET users_id = 40;
END IF;
 
END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it for a second and you'll realize the first problem: if what you actually need here is an `AFTER` update trigger... then what would a `BEFORE` update trigger do?

`AFTER UPDATE` means *after the update query has already changed the row data*.  What you are actually looking to is `BEFORE UPDATE` -- you want to hijack the update in mid-stream, before the table data actually gets changed, and potentially modify the values that will actually be written to the database.

```
UPDATE loans SET users_id = 40;
```

There are two problems with this.  First, you know what an `UPDATE` without `WHERE` does... right?  It updates *all the rows* in the table.  Luckily, the server didn't let you do that.  But the solution is not to add a `WHERE` clause -- it's this:

```
IF(NEW.users_id = 32 AND NEW.Principal > 50000) THEN
  SET NEW.users_id = 40;
END IF;
```

The `NEW` pseudotable contains the row data that the user has tried to cause the `UPDATE` (that fired the trigger) to write to the row.  You are in a `BEFORE UPDATE ... FOR EACH ROW` trigger, so setting `NEW` values overrides anything the user tried to do... which appears to be what you are wanting to accomplish.